# What is this device used by a networking technology company?

Tags: fiber, hardware

I recently saw two men open up the sidewalk in a major German city. It seemed they dug out this device

[image]

Both men worked for a networking technology company, so I hope this is on topic here.

**What is this device?**

Comment: huh, I also saw them doing this outside my home. Wonder if it's a city-wide or country-wide upgrade, and if so, what for.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Connecting two fiber trunks is a tedious process. Those are splice cassettes for optical fiber - each single fiber is fusion spliced and looped into one of the cassettes for protection. Afterwards the whole box is sealed and buried or put in a cabinet.

Answer (score 17):

They're a fiber splicing crew.  The white plastic trays are used to organize fiber connections.

A waterproof enclosure will protect the whole assembly from debris when their job is finished, and the enclosure will be stowed somewhere, e.g. in an underground chamber or an above-ground pedestal.